# How to modify the timestamp for a files "creation date" to show only the date, without time in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, date-time

Okay, so I know I can change the format of the time-stamp in my computer settings. If I change short time to blank, then I have the outcome I am looking for. However, it changes ALL my system short times to blank. This is not what I want. I want ONLY windows file explorer to show the date time-stamp without the hours and minutes.

Is there a way to change this setting by editing the registry, or something else? It is DRIVING ME CRAZY!!!!!

Comment: If it turns out to not be possible with the Registry, one could create a custom [column handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776831(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That would actually be perfect... Thanks Ben. Now to figure out how! I don't mind doing the research to figure it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!